# Can't save settings to database using Setting API

Tags: settings-api

I wrote a simple test code for testing saving data using Setting API, but it doesn't seem to work. it realy driving me crazy. Please help me point out the problem, thanks!

```
function test_add_options_page() {
    add_menu_page(
        'Test Save Option',
        'Test Save',
        'manage_options',
        'testpage',
        'test_save_page'
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'test_add_options_page');

function test_save_page() {
    ?>
        <form action="options.php" method="post">
            <?php 
                settings_errors();
                settings_fields('testpage');
                do_settings_sections('testpage');
                submit_button();
            ?>
        </form>

    <?php   
}

function test_add_settings() {
    add_settings_section(
        'section_1',
        'Section 1',
        'output_section_desc',
        'testpage'
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'field_id',
        'Field Title',
        'add_field_callback',
        'testpage',
        'section_1'
    );

    register_setting('testpage', 'testpage');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'test_add_settings');

function output_section_desc() {
    echo 'Section Description...';
}

function add_field_callback() {
    echo '<input type="test" id="field_id" />';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your input field is missing a `name` attribute.
The `id` attribute is a unique identifier, mainly used by the visitor's browser, to target elements via CSS or JS.
The `name` attribute is an identifier for form elements to be used in the `POST` or `GET` request on form submission.

Also, `test` is *not a valid input type*.

So far, that's generic and not at all specific to the [*Settings API*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API).

Your callback should hence look like this:

```
function add_field_callback() {
    echo '<input type="text" id="field_id" name="testpage[\'field_id\']"/>';
}
```

The *Settings API* saves options in option groups. You defined your group to be called `'testpage'`. Hence to retrieve the saved value, you'd do something along the lines of:

```
$testpage_values = get_option( 'testpage' );
$field_value = isset( $testpage_values['field_id'] ) ? $testpage_values['field_id'] : 'Not set.';
echo $field_value;
```

Comment: Got it. thanks Pille, for the quick answer, it's clear and detailed.